# Insert values using the procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've created Procedure in order to insert new employees, but the problem is, it is not inserting. I need to pass the attributes values as parameters. This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_new(p_empid IN employees.employee_id%type,
                                             p_fname IN employees.first_name%type,
                                             p_lname IN employees.last_name%type,
                                             p_email IN employees.email%type,
                                             p_pnum IN employees.phone_number%type,
                                             p_hdate IN employees.hire_date%type,
                                             p_jid IN employees.job_id%type,
                                             p_salary IN employees.salary%type,
                                             p_comm IN employees.commission_pct%type,
                                             p_mid IN employees.manager_id%type,
                                             p_deptid IN employees.department_id%type) AS
                                       
    v_empid employees.employee_id%type;
    v_fname employees.first_name%type;
    v_lname employees.last_name%type;
    v_email employees.email%type;
    v_pnum employees.phone_number%type;
    v_hdate employees.hire_date%type;
    v_jid employees.job_id%type;
    v_salary employees.salary%type;
    v_comm employees.commission_pct%type;
    v_mid employees.manager_id%type;
    v_deptid employees.department_id%type;

    CURSOR c_emp IS
    select employee_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone_number,
    hire_date, job_id, salary, commission_pct, manager_id, department_id
    from employees
    WHERE employee_id=p_empid;
    
BEGIN
    OPEN c_emp;
    FETCH c_emp INTO
    v_empid, v_fname, v_lname, v_email, v_pnum, v_hdate,
    v_jid, v_salary, v_comm, v_mid, v_deptid; 
    INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(employee_id, first_name, last_name, email, phone_number,
    hire_date, job_id, salary, commission_pct, manager_id, department_id)
    VALUES (v_empid, v_fname, v_lnamw, v_email, v_pnum, v_hdate,
    v_jid, v_salary, v_comm, v_mid, v_deptid);   
    CLOSE c_emp;
END;
/
```

I don't know which is wrong in this one. And this is my code for calling procedure

For calling Procedure:

```
DECLARE
    v_empid employees.employee_id%type:=600;
    v_fname employees.first_name%type:='text';
    v_lname employees.last_name%type:='string';
    v_email employees.email%type:='string';
    v_pnum employees.phone_number%type:=123456789;
    v_hdate employees.hire_date%type:='18-SEP-2000';
    v_jid employees.job_id%type:='string';
    v_salary employees.salary%type:=4000;
    v_comm employees.commission_pct%type:=0.5;
    v_mid employees.manager_id%type:=105;
    v_deptid employees.department_id%type:=30;
BEGIN
    p_new(v_empid, v_fname, v_lname,
    v_email,v_pnum,v_hdate,v_jid,v_salary,v_comm,
    v_mid,v_deptid);
END;
/
```

I don't know why it is not inserting. I am having an error of unique constraint

Comment: You are trying to insert (new) rows by selecting them from the target table. Of course you cannot insert something that doesn't exist using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't need a cursor nor a loop while inserting data (at least, not with such a procedure). Also, you have to use variables you declared, not the ones you didn't.

Sample table:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE employees
  2  (
  3     employee_id      NUMBER,
  4     first_name       VARCHAR2 (10),
  5     last_name        VARCHAR2 (10),
  6     email            VARCHAR2 (10),
  7     phone_number     VARCHAR2 (10),
  8     hire_date        DATE,
  9     job_id           VARCHAR2 (10),
 10     salary           NUMBER,
 11     commission_pct   NUMBER,
 12     manager_id       NUMBER,
 13     department_id    NUMBER
 14  );

Table created.
```

Procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE p_new (
  2     p_empid   IN employees.employee_id%TYPE,
  3     p_fname   IN employees.first_name%TYPE,
  4     p_lname   IN employees.last_name%TYPE,
  5     p_email   IN employees.email%TYPE,
  6     p_pnum    IN employees.phone_number%TYPE,
  7     p_hdate   IN employees.hire_date%TYPE,
  8     p_jid     IN employees.job_id%TYPE,
  9     p_salary  IN employees.salary%TYPE,
 10     p_comm    IN employees.commission_pct%TYPE,
 11     p_mid     IN employees.manager_id%TYPE,
 12     p_deptid  IN employees.department_id%TYPE)
 13  AS
 14  BEGIN
 15     INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES (employee_id,
 16                            first_name,
 17                            last_name,
 18                            email,
 19                            phone_number,
 20                            hire_date,
 21                            job_id,
 22                            salary,
 23                            commission_pct,
 24                            manager_id,
 25                            department_id)
 26          VALUES (p_empid,
 27                  p_fname,
 28                  p_lname,
 29                  p_email,
 30                  p_pnum,
 31                  p_hdate,
 32                  p_jid,
 33                  p_salary,
 34                  p_comm,
 35                  p_mid,
 36                  p_deptid);
 37  END;
 38  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_empid   employees.employee_id%TYPE := 600;
  3     v_fname   employees.first_name%TYPE := 'text';
  4     v_lname   employees.last_name%TYPE := 'string';
  5     v_email   employees.email%TYPE := 'string';
  6     v_pnum    employees.phone_number%TYPE := 123456789;
  7     v_hdate   employees.hire_date%TYPE := DATE '2000-09-18'; -- DATE, not STRING! '18-SEP-2000';
  8     v_jid     employees.job_id%TYPE := 'string';
  9     v_salary  employees.salary%TYPE := 4000;
 10     v_comm    employees.commission_pct%TYPE := 0.5;
 11     v_mid     employees.manager_id%TYPE := 105;
 12     v_deptid  employees.department_id%TYPE := 30;
 13  BEGIN
 14     p_new (v_empid,
 15            v_fname,
 16            v_lname,
 17            v_email,
 18            v_pnum,
 19            v_hdate,
 20            v_jid,
 21            v_salary,
 22            v_comm,
 23            v_mid,
 24            v_deptid);
 25  END;
 26  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME  EMAIL      PHONE_NUMB HIRE_DATE  JOB_ID
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
    SALARY COMMISSION_PCT MANAGER_ID DEPARTMENT_ID
---------- -------------- ---------- -------------
        600 text       string     string     123456789  18.09.2000 string
      4000             ,5        105            30


SQL>
```

Comment: I am having an error where the column is not allowed from procedure

Comment: Sure you do (because you misspelled `v_lnamw`), but fixing that won't help in making *your* code work.

Comment: When I am trying to insert, I am having this error "unique constraint (%s.%s) violated", ORA-00001: unique constraint (HR.EMP_EMAIL_UK) violated

Comment: Don't send ID values which are already being used. Or, handle the exception.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having an error of unique constraint

Then there is already an employee in the table with an identical value in a column constrained by a unique or primary key constraint.

You need to change the values you are inserting into the table so that you do not insert duplicates.

If you have the table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (
  employee_id    NUMBER(8,0)
                 GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
                 CONSTRAINT employees__employee_id__pk PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name     VARCHAR2(50),
  last_name      VARCHAR2(25),
  email          VARCHAR2(250)
                 CONSTRAINT employees__email__u UNIQUE,
  phone_number   VARCHAR2(12)
                 CONSTRAINT employees__phone_number__u UNIQUE,
  hire_date      DATE,
  job_id         NUMBER(8,0)
                 -- CONSTRAINT employees__job_id__fk REFERENCES jobs(id)
                 ,
  salary         NUMBER(10,2),
  commission_pct NUMBER(5,2),
  manager_id     NUMBER
                 CONSTRAINT employees__manager_id__fk REFERENCES employees (employee_id),
  department_id  NUMBER(8,0)
                 -- CONSTRAINT employees__department_id__fk REFERENCES departments (id)
);
```

Then the primary key will be generated by the `IDENTITY` column (which is available from Oracle 12) and the employee also has unique constraints on e-mail and phone number (you have not provided the DDL statement for your table so this is only an example).

Then you can insert a new user using:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE p_new(
  p_empid  IN employees.employee_id%type,
  p_fname  IN employees.first_name%type,
  p_lname  IN employees.last_name%type,
  p_email  IN employees.email%type,
  p_pnum   IN employees.phone_number%type,
  p_hdate  IN employees.hire_date%type,
  p_jid    IN employees.job_id%type,
  p_salary IN employees.salary%type,
  p_comm   IN employees.commission_pct%type,
  p_mid    IN employees.manager_id%type,
  p_deptid IN employees.department_id%type
)
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    phone_number,
    hire_date,
    job_id,
    salary,
    commission_pct,
    manager_id,
    department_id
  ) VALUES (
    p_fname,
    p_lname,
    p_email,
    p_pnum,
    p_hdate,
    p_jid,
    p_salary,
    p_comm,
    p_mid,
    p_deptid
  );   
END;
/
```

The `employee_id` is automatically generated by the `IDENTITY` column and you do not need to insert it; however, for example given the constraints on the table, if you insert duplicate e-mails or phone numbers then you would still get an exception for `UNIQUE constraint violated`.

You can insert the value using:

```sql
BEGIN
  p_new(
    'text',
    'string',
    'string',
    '0123456789',
    DATE '2000-09-18',
    'string',
    4000,
    0.5,
    105,
    30
  );
END;
/
```